# How to group matched results in Neo4J/Cypher

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm very new to Neo4J and Cypher and I have to work on a highly relational dataset. The graph model looks like this

[image]

Where in my data I have multiple instances of C,A,Le, and only a few instances of Lo, R, F.

I am looking to find a way to get the following: For each unique pair of Lo-F, get all the C and count how many unique C for each such pair.

In other words, I want all the groups of `C` that share the same `LO` and `F`, and I need my results to tell me:

- How many unique `C`
- Common LO
- Common F

My humble start was to `MATCH` a pattern like this (directions of arrows are mostly irrelevant for this problem):

```
MATCH (c:C)--(:A)--(le:LE)--(:R)--(f:F),
      (le)--(lo:LO)
RETURN f, lo, c LIMIT 5
```

Which returns all matched patterns. I then proceeded to attempt to use `collect` and `count`. For example,

```
MATCH (c:C)--(:A)--(le:LE)--(:R)--(f:F),
      (le)--(lo:LO)
RETURN f, lo, collect(c), COUNT(*) as _counts
ORDER BY _counts LIMIT 5
```

which seems to be giving me a table with unique f-lo pairs and the list of `C` plus the counts. However, the `collect(c)` column have repeated `C`, and as such the `_counts` are not correct. I then attempted to introduce `DISTINCT`:

```
MATCH (c:C)--(:A)--(le:LE)--(:R)--(f:F),
      (le)--(lo:LO)
RETURN f, lo, collect(DISTINCT c), COUNT(*) as _counts
ORDER BY _counts LIMIT 5
```

But I have the same results...

I have googled extensively, but since I am also fairly new to SQL I find most of the tutorials and examples difficult to follow in their SQL-analogy.

Also, would this be better framed as a clustering algorithm? I have installed the `algo` plugin but I have struggled to understand how to prepare the match for the `.stream` method in order to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. This should work for you:

```
MATCH (c:C)<--(:A)-->(le:LE)-->(:R)-->(f:F),
      (le)-->(lo:LO)
WITH f, lo, COLLECT(DISTINCT c) AS cs
RETURN f, lo, cs, SIZE(cs) as _counts
ORDER BY _counts LIMIT 5
```

Note, also, that it is more efficient to include relationship directionality in a query.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But now I have all _counts = 1. I think I tried this before and encountered the same issue.